# Inverse of $A+b^{T}b$ and $A+B^{T}+B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n$ $\times$ $n$ positive-definite matrix, $b$ is a $1$ $\times$ $n$ vector. Assume that $A+b^{T}b$ is invertible.
Is there a formula to compute the inverse of $A+b^{T}b$, where $T$ is transponse?

Thanks!

Another questions:
What is the inverse of $A+B^{T}+B$, where $B$ is a $n$ $\times$ $n$ matrix, given that it is invertible?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't ask two questions in a single question -- you see, your second question did not get answered

Answer (score 3):

The [Sherman-Morrison forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) states that if $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $u,v$ are $n \times 1$ vectors with $1+v^TA^{-1}u \neq 0$, then $A+uv^T$ is invertible and $$(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \dfrac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}.$$

Applying that formula here with $u = v = b^T$ yields $$(A+b^Tb)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \dfrac{A^{-1}b^TbA^{-1}}{1+bA^{-1}b^T}.$$ Note that since $A$ is positive definite in your problem, $A^{-1}$ is also positive definite, and thus, $1+bA^{-1}b^T \ge 1 > 0$.